# How do I run a pinned taskbar program as a an administrator using only keyboard

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts

So I use the <kbd>WinKey</kbd> + <kbd>Number</kbd> to launch programs from my taskbar a lot and I am wondering if I can get this keyboard shortcut to launch a certain program as an admin.

I do not want to left click on anything, it must be a keyboard shortcut only.

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Number</kbd> launches your program as an administrator.

Comment: Well you answered your own question :)

Comment: So how do you do it in Windows 7? :P

Comment: @avirk - Exactly the same way?

Comment: @Ramhound so its not specific about Windows 8, that's what I want to point out. :P